# Advertise Beacons in React Native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I was trying to advertise beacons in react-native app. I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-beacons-manager and https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-kontaktio.
Both packages are only capturing beacons but not advertising.

Is there any module in react-native that actually advertise the beacons?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ibeacon-simulator

Comment: It is working, thanks @TejashwiKalpTaru

Comment: I am wondering, if how can I send some data with the beacons being advertised?

Comment: I don't think that this is feasible, you are only allowed to advertise UUID, Major, Minor and may be a name.